# Shapefile creating "leaky" overlay in Google My Map after QGIS KML export

Tags: qgis, shapefile, google-maps, kml

California has published, as shapefiles, maps of the various Fire Hazard Severity Zones in the state. I'm trying to use QGIS to convert these into a KML that I can then use as a Layer in a Google My Map. This is generally working well, however, on some Google pages and mobile apps, it seems like *one* of the KMLs is "leaking" or "bleeding" and showing a colored overlay on the entire map, and not just the bounded regions.

**How can I clean up the file and properly view the Layer?**

There are screenshots below. The steps to reproduce the issue are:

1. Download the State Responsibility Area (SRA) map shapefiles for Contra Costa county from [the Cal Fire website](https://osfm.fire.ca.gov/divisions/wildfire-prevention-planning-engineering/wildland-hazards-building-codes/fire-hazard-severity-zones-maps/).
2. Drag the entire `fhszs7sn.zip` file into the Layers panel a new project in QGIS (I'm using 3.8.2-Zanzibar), accepting the default CRS import settings.
3. Right click the new layer and go to Export -> Save Feature As. Select KML from the dropdown at the top, and leave the other settings as their defaults. (The KML file I'm having trouble with is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D-RhjiYIzUHLqK7K25-BtK4DyHzpoHQY).)
4. Create a new Google My Map using the "+" icon at the lower right of [this page](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/). (My test map is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vetEr6zWugMJOZhGz30lyfVS-N_ib9lA&usp=sharing).)
5. Import the .kml file into a new Layer, click individual styles, and select `HAZ_CLASS` and select colors that are easy to distinguish.

At this point, everything should look normal. However, if you view the map in either/both of the following two ways:

6. Open the [main Google Maps page](https://www.google.com/maps), not the My Maps page above.
7. Click the three-line "hamburger icon" in the upper left, select "Your Places", then "Maps", then your just-created map. (I can't link to this directly for my sample map.)

Or:

8. Open the Google Maps app for iOS on your iPhone or iPad. (This is my primary use case.)
9. Tap the three-line "hamburger icon" in the upper left, select "Your Places", scroll the list at the top to the right if necessary, then tap "Maps", then your just-created map.

You should see the overlay covering the entire map. I'm able to distinguish by color that it's the "Very High" FSHZ that is causing the issue. I've tried using some QGIS tools to fix it, including "Check validity" and "Fix geometries", but neither seemed to help.

I'm relatively new to GIS. For what it's worth, the Alameda county LRA shapefile *also* had an error, but I was able to get QGIS to fix that one.

[image: Map with leaky overlay]

[image: Map without leaky overlay]

Comment: Can you share a copy or sample of the KML file you're having trouble with, and we can try to help debug?

Comment: @ChristiaanAdams Sure, thanks! I added this link to step #3 above: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D-RhjiYIzUHLqK7K25-BtK4DyHzpoHQY. (Let me know if there's somewhere better to upload it.)